# Receiving Intermittent Server Error from Application

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, php-7.2

Anyone seen the below error message from PHP7 on Google App Engine standard environment?

```
Error: Server Error 
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

Example log from GCP:

```
xx.xxx.xxx.xx - - [01/Jul/2019:09:16:11 +0100] "GET /api/courses HTTP/1.1" 500 - - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36" "example.com" ms=12009 cpu_ms=3303 cpm_usd=0 loading_request=0 instance=00c61b117c915eddeba77b2a4f20a2ae2b81fc81a941138beb270170b47b91aedffd87f2 app_engine_release=1.9.71 trace_id=1f2cdcf1c2ea56bc5ebf7cf12577b057
```

I don't see any logs in my PHP application so don't think the issue is there, but I also can't see any details of the error in GCP.

Where do I need to look? Any help appreciated!

Thanks

EDIT

Using `gcloud app logs tail` reveals the following errors, no idea how to fix these or if they're the cause of the issue!

```
2019-07-01 19:21:29 default[20190701t094939]  nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /tmp/google-config/nginx.conf:3

2019-07-01 19:21:27 default[20190701t094939]  [01-Jul-2019 19:21:27] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)

2019-07-01 19:21:18 default[20190701t094939]  [01-Jul-2019 19:21:18] WARNING: [pool app] child 25 exited on signal 7 (SIGBUS) after 0.718745 seconds from start
```

EDIT 2

I've added caching to a pretty heavy API end point that has stopped these errors from happening, as you can see after I deployed the change on July 1st in the evening. Looking at the 500 logs they seem to correlate with spikes in traffic so if I had to guess maybe the instance was hitting a Memory/CPU limit?!

[image: GCP request graph]

Comment: This usually means that your software running in App Engine crashed. Use Stackdriver logging, exception handling, etc. to find the problem.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley, have updated post with further logs.

Comment: The signal SIGBUS means that your program behaved in a way that caused the OS to kill it. Without your code and deployment files, no idea why.